# how to display more related products in magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento1.9.3, related-products

As a beginner i dont know much about custom .my query is On my product page it shows  3 related product only. i want to add one more related product here. how to do this. 
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see more related products in frontend by default, then you can edit code and set your count to show more related products. If you are using custom theme then go to 
`app/design/frontend/Your_Package/Your_Theme/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml`

and check for

```
foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
```

in that file. There you add condition for checking count as per your requirement. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thankx for help but could you tell me how to used count here . my code is

Comment: <ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-related">
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>

Comment: You can write like this:  <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php if ($i++ == 4) break; ?> 
                    <li class="item">
                        <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>

Comment: no bro, Its still display only 3 related product .. i want to add one more here .i had already add 5 related product from backend but displaying only 3

Comment: Is your cache enabled?If yes then clear the cache once and check and let me know if it is still showing 3.

Comment: no cache are not enable. and related products still 3 only

Comment: I have used the same code, it shows 4 products in frontend. And if you are using rwd theme then by default it must shows all related products.

Comment: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list

Is it right location m Using these theme D:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default\electronics but there were no file thatsy i choose base path

Comment: Do not edit that base file. Are you using any custom theme or rwd theme? If rwd theme,then go to app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml  and edit it. Magento uses rwd theme by default.

Comment: Ok, understood. If you are using "electronics" theme under default package then copy the file from base/rwd in your theme with same folder path and edit it and check.

Comment: file is missing on my theme location there were only upsell file present 
D:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default\electronics\template\catalog\product\list/upsell.phtml

Comment: Copy the related.phtml from base/rwd and paste it in your theme. path should look like app/design/frontend/default/electronics/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml.

Comment: its working Thankx for help Bro

Comment: Sounds great :) Please accept the answer as useful